# from typing import generator fail

Tags: python

I need help interpreting the following error message and possibly troubleshooting what steps to take next as my google searching hasn't gotten me anywhere.

````
>>> from typing import asyncgenerator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    from typing import asyncgenerator
ImportError: cannot import name 'asyncgenerator' from 'typing' (C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\typing.py) ```
````

Comment: It seems to be saying that the `typing` module does not have anything called `asyncgenerator`

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
from typing import AsyncGenerator
```

`AsyncGenerator` uses capital letters. Technically, `asyncgenerator` does not exist because the name does not match exactly.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that was the way to go when I opened typing.py. But ofcourse I was trying to follow a tutorial to the letter. Thank you so much

Comment: @NathanHarrell you're welcome, I would appreciate an accepted answer if you think it helped!

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the name is not supposed to be all lowercase. Try the command

```
from typing import AsyncGenerator
```